# Сборка в gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Нужно настроить build.gradle, чтоб релизная сборка получилась несколькими apk с одинаковым `versionCode` но с разным `versionName`. К примеру у одного apk `versionName "1.4.1-a"`, а у другого  apk `versionName "1.4.1-b"`.
Помню когда-то делал apk для разных архитектур, но не могу вспомнить принцип...

В принципе можно после каждого билда менять `versionName`, но это не удобно и долго.

Comment: посмотрите как использовать flavors в градле

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
productFlavors { 
    version_a { 
        versionName defaultConfig.versionName + "-a"
    } 
    version_b{ 
        versionName defaultConfig.versionName + "-b"
    } 
}
```

в `defaultConfig` версию нужно указывать, как `1.4.1`
используя `productFlavors`, вы можете настроить и другие опции.

Пример скрипта для билда обеих flavor:

```
gradle clean assembleVersion_aDebug assembleVersion_bDebug assembleVersion_aRelease assembleVersion_bRelease
```

Comment: flavors я пробовал, получилось так что все равно приходится собирать  несколько раз. Только я делал так: Flavors { и дальше как у Вас.

Comment: @ВладимирSeos-Lab, вы можете из консоли собрать последовательно все, что вам надо

Comment: @ВладимирSeos-Lab, я именно так у себя и делаю. Сейчас прикреплю пример скрипта

Comment: если Вас не затруднит, приведите пример сборки из консоли.

Comment: Спасибо, а нужно находится в корневой директории или в app?

Comment: @ВладимирSeos-Lab, стыдно признавать, но я не помню :) попробуйте и в корне проекта, и в директории модуля

Comment: В общем нужно находится в корневой директории. Спасибо за помощь!